# Problema ao consultar o cargo cadastrado onde mostra valor null

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, getters-setters

Olá sou novo em programação mas estou desenvolvendo um código por meio do curso do Java avançado do site do Bradesco e lá a ultima parte é montar um sistema, porem estou com um problema na tela de consulta do cargo cadastrado. Eu tenho uma tela de cadastro onde digita um nome de cargo e ao apertar no botão de adicionar cargo ele envia o nome do cargo q eu digitei ao banco de dados porem ele está indo com valor Null e quando eu vou fazer a consulta na tela de consultas ele não aparece o nome do cargo que eu digitei por está indo Null, vou enviar o código das duas telinhas.

1 tela de cadastro de cargo

```
package sistema.telas;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import sistema.BancoDeDados;
import sistema.entidades.Cargo;

public class CargosInserir extends JPanel {

    JLabel labelTitulo, labelCargo;
    JTextField campoCargo;
    JButton botaoGravar;
    
    public CargosInserir() {
        criarComponentes();
        criarEventos();
    }
    
    private void criarComponentes() {
        //Na linha 34, estamos definindo que não usaremos nenhum gerenciador de layout.
        setLayout(null);
        
        /*Nas linhas 37 a 41 estamos instanciando os componentes da tela:
         - Os componentes JLabel estão sendo inicializados com textos e alinhamentos especificos.
         - Já o componente JButton, está sendo inicializado somente com seu texto de exibição.*/
        labelTitulo = new JLabel("Cadastro de Cargo", JLabel.CENTER);
        labelTitulo.setFont(new Font(labelTitulo.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 20));
        labelCargo = new JLabel("Nome do cargo", JLabel.LEFT);
        campoCargo = new JTextField();
        botaoGravar = new JButton("Adicionar Cargo");
        
        //Na linha 46 a 49, Definimos o posicionamento e o tamanho dos componentes na tela.
        labelTitulo.setBounds(20, 20, 660, 40);
        labelCargo.setBounds(150, 120, 400, 20);
        campoCargo.setBounds(150, 140, 400, 40);
        botaoGravar.setBounds(250, 380, 200, 40);
        
        //Na linha 52 a 55, adicionamos os componentes à tela.
        add(labelTitulo);
        add(labelCargo);
        add(campoCargo);
        add(botaoGravar);
        
        //Na linha 58, tornamos á tela visivel.
        setVisible(true);
    }
    /*Nas linhas 61 a 73,  estamos definindo que, ao ser acionado, o botão
     Adicionar Cargo irá criar uma instância da entidade Cargo atribuíndo ao cargo
     o valor do texto digitado no JTextField campoCargo e por fim chamar o
     método sqlInserirCargo.*/
    private void criarEventos() {
        botaoGravar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Cargo novoCargo = new Cargo();
                novoCargo.setNome(campoCargo.getText());
            
                sqlInserirCargo(novoCargo);
            }
        });
    }
        //nas linhas 74 a 78, validamos o conteúdo do campo Nome do Cargo
        private void sqlInserirCargo(Cargo novoCargo) {
            
            //validando nome
            if(campoCargo.getText().length() <= 3 /*Caso não possua mais de 3 caractres, aparecerá a seguinte mensagem ao usuário.*/)  {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preencha o nome corretamente");
            return;
            }
        
        /*Nas linhas 86 a 106, realizamos a conexão com o banco de dados para inserir um novo cargo, de acordo com os dados que foram
        adicionados ao campo Nome do Cargo.*/
            
        //Conexão
        Connection conexao;
        //Instrução SQL
        Statement instrucaoSQL;
        //Resultados
        ResultSet resultados;
        
        try {
            //conectando ao banco de dados
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BancoDeDados.stringDeConexao, BancoDeDados.usuario, BancoDeDados.senha);
            
            //criando a instrução SQL
            instrucaoSQL = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            instrucaoSQL.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cargos (nome) VALUES ('"+novoCargo.getNome()+"')");
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cargo adicionado com sucesso!");       
                    
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao adicionar o Cargo.");
            Logger.getLogger(CargosInserir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

agora vou está enviando a tela 2 q é a de consulta de cargo

```
package sistema.telas;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import sistema.BancoDeDados;
import sistema.entidades.Cargo;

//Criaremos a classe CargosConsultar a partir da linha 25, Conforme a indicação no codigo.

public class CargosConsultar extends JPanel {

    Cargo cargoAtual;
    JLabel labelTitulo, labelCargo;
    JTextField campoCargo;
    JButton botaoPesquisar, botaoEditar, botaoExcluir;
    DefaultListModel<Cargo> listasCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel();
    JList<Cargo> listaCargos;
    
    public CargosConsultar() {
        criarComponentes();
        criarEventos();
    }
    private void criarComponentes() {
        setLayout(null); // Definimos que não será usado nenhum gerenciador de layout.
        
        //Nas linhas 43 a 55, instanciamos os componentes da tela.
        labelTitulo = new JLabel("Consulta de Cargos", JLabel.CENTER);
        labelTitulo.setFont(new Font(labelTitulo.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 20));
        labelCargo = new JLabel("Nome do cargo", JLabel.LEFT);
        campoCargo = new JTextField();
        botaoPesquisar = new JButton("Pesquisar Cargo");
        botaoEditar = new JButton("Editar Cargo");
        botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
        botaoExcluir = new JButton("Excluir Cargo");
        botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
        listasCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel();
        listaCargos = new JList();
        listaCargos.setModel(listasCargosModelo);
        listaCargos.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        
        //Nas linhas 58 a 64, definimos o posicionamento e o tamanho dos componentes na tela.
        labelTitulo.setBounds(20, 20, 660, 40);
        labelCargo.setBounds(150, 120, 400, 20);
        campoCargo.setBounds(150, 140, 400, 40);
        botaoPesquisar.setBounds(560, 140, 130, 40);
        listaCargos.setBounds(150, 200, 400, 240);
        botaoEditar.setBounds(560, 360, 130, 40);
        botaoExcluir.setBounds(560, 400, 130, 40);
        
        //Nas linhas 67 a 72 adicionamos os componentes a tela.
        add(labelTitulo);
        add(labelCargo);
        add(campoCargo);
        add(listaCargos);
        add(botaoPesquisar);
        add(botaoEditar);
        add(botaoExcluir);
        
        //Tornando a tela visível.
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    private void criarEventos() {
        botaoPesquisar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sqlPesquisarCargos(campoCargo.getText());
            }
        });
        botaoEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        /*Nas linha 95 a 100 , definimos que, ao ser acionado, o botão Excluir Cargo irá
        chamar o método sqlDeletarCargo.*/
        botaoExcluir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sqlDeletarCargo();
            }
        });
        /*Nas 103 a 116, definimos que, ao se selecionar algum cargo na lista, este será
         armazenado na variável cargoAtual, e os botões Editar Cargo e Excluir Cargo serão habilitados. */
        listaCargos.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                cargoAtual = listaCargos.getSelectedValue();
                if(cargoAtual == null) {
                    botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
                    botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    botaoEditar.setEnabled(true);
                    botaoExcluir.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
        /*Nas linhas 118 a 147, realizamos a conexão com o banco de dados para obtermos, por meio dele, todos os cargos
        cadastrados e adicioná-los à lista de seleção.*/
        private void sqlPesquisarCargos(String nome) {
            //Conexão
            Connection conexao;
            //Instrução SQL
            Statement instrucaoSQL;
            //Resultados
            ResultSet resultados;
            
            try {
                // Conectando ao banco de dados
                conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BancoDeDados.stringDeConexao, BancoDeDados.usuario, BancoDeDados.senha);
                
                // Criando A intrução SQL
                instrucaoSQL = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                resultados = instrucaoSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cargos WHERE nome like '%"+nome+"%'");
                
                listasCargosModelo.clear();
                
                while (resultados.next()) {
                    Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
                    cargo.setId(resultados.getInt("id"));
                    cargo.setNome(resultados.getString("Nome"));
                    
                    listasCargosModelo.addElement(cargo);
                }
            
            }catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Ocorreu um erro ao consultas os Cargos.");
                Logger.getLogger(CargosInserir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
    /*Ao ser acionado o botão Excluir Cargo irá executar o método sqlDeletarCargo. na sintaxe das linhas 149 a 171, podemos ver que esse método irá
     irá se conectar com o banco de dados e executar a instrução SQL que irá remover o cargo selecionado.*/
    private void sqlDeletarCargo() {
        
        int confirmacao = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Deseja realmente excluir o Cargo "+cargoAtual.getNome()+"?", "Excluir", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(confirmacao == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            // Conexão
            Connection conexao;
            // Intrução SQL
            Statement instrucaoSQL;
            // Resultados
            ResultSet resultados;
            
            try {
                // Conectando ao banco de dados
                conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BancoDeDados.stringDeConexao, BancoDeDados.usuario, BancoDeDados.senha);
                
                // Criando a instrução SQL
                instrucaoSQL = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                instrucaoSQL.executeUpdate("DELETE cargos WHERE id="+cargoAtual.getId()+"");
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cargo deletado com sucesso!");
            } catch(SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao excluir o Cargo.");
                Logger.getLogger(CargosInserir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Além disso no curso mostra q tem q ser feito um Package com o nome de Sistemas.entidades e dentro desse Package é a onde está a classe Cargo, é aqui onde eu acho que está o problema, pois é aqui onde fica os códigos para a classe cargo onde essa classe é utilizada tanto na classe CargosInserir, quanto na classe CargosConsultar, vou está enviando os códigos dessa classe Cargo...

```
package sistema.entidades;
public class Cargo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setNome(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }


    public void setId(int int1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    public String getNome() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

eu acredito que o erro esteja nesse return null, que seja por isso que esteja aparecendo em branco quando eu aperto pra consultar ou quando eu vou enviar o nome do cargo ao banco de dados ele envia em branco, porem já pesquisei e não sei como eu posso mudar esse return dos metodos getNome e getId, tipo quando eu digitasse o nome do cargo e clicasse em cadastrar e fosse salvo no banco de dados corretamente o nome do cargo que eu digitei e fosse consultar na tela de consulta, ao digitar o nome inserido teria que aparecer o valor cadastrado no banco de dados, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar, porque estou muito entusiasmado e empolgado com esse programa e gostaria de finalizar esse sistema, e antes que alguém falem que é erro de banco de dados não é pois está sendo enviado os dados do id no banco então a ligação está sendo feito o problema deve está nisso que eu falei ou em outro lugar que eu não esteja vendo, se alguém poder me ajudar eu agradeço de todo meu coração, a e antes de finalizar eu estou usando o eclipse ultima atualização até o momento e o programa é na versão do java 14...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafael, a sua classe Cargo não possui atributos e os métodos getter estão retorando Null sempre. Declare os atributos "id" e "nome" na classe Cargo e atualize os métodos acessores (getters e setters):

```
package sistema.entidades;

public class Cargo {
    
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Com esse ajuste, o nome do cargo passará a ser salvo.

Answer (score 0):

agora quando eu faço o cadastro do cargo e vou consultar ele mostra como resultado isso. sistema.entidades.Cargo@41217cf0 ou algum outro nome igual a esse q mostrei e não mostra o nome que foi digitado e no banco de dados no campo cargo aparece o cargo digitado na tela porem quando consulta na tela de consulta de cargos aparece esse sistema.entidades.Cargo@41217cf0 ou algum outro nome parecido com esse codigo. e como n entendi direito essa parte de atualizar os getters e os setters, acho q é isso q n esta indo. tipo onde eu tenho q mudar, na classe de consultar e em qual linha.

Answer (score 0):

Essa é as linhas onde tem o getter na class consultarCargo

private void criarEventos() {
botaoPesquisar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
sqlPesquisarCargos(campoCargo.getText());
}
});

listaCargos.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
cargoAtual = listaCargos.getSelectedValue();
if(cargoAtual == null) {
botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
}else {
botaoEditar.setEnabled(true);
botaoExcluir.setEnabled(true);
}
}
});
}

private void sqlPesquisarCargos(String nome) {
Connection conexao;
Statement instrucaoSQL;
ResultSet resultados;
try {
conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BancoDeDados.stringDeConexao, BancoDeDados.usuario, BancoDeDados.senha);

```
            instrucaoSQL = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            resultados = instrucaoSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cargos WHERE nome like '%"+nome+"%'");
            
            listasCargosModelo.clear();
            
            while (resultados.next()) {
                Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
                cargo.setId(resultados.getInt("id"));
                cargo.setNome(resultados.getString("nome"));
                
                listasCargosModelo.addElement(cargo);
            }
        
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Ocorreu um erro ao consultas os Cargos.");
            Logger.getLogger(CargosInserir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Onde eu tenho que mudar, quem nem vc falo q preciso atualizar os metodos acessores...